# Is there a simple way to add a column in the AspNetRoles table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

The AspNetRoles table has 2 columns "Id" and "Name". I need to add a third one: "Module(nvarchar(256), null)".

I found some articles on my search but the majority from years ago and a bit complex to me. I'm asking if there a simple way to do it using the EF?

Comment: Any reason you can't just do it in SQL?

Comment: For what I know so far, if you do it this way the column won't be visible in the EF code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom class that inherits from IdentityRole and add whatever properties you want in that class:

1. Create a custom class as shown below:

   ```html
    public class CustomIdentityRole : IdentityRole
       {
           public string NewColumn { get; set; }

       }
   ```
2. Run EF migration command to generate the table model as shown below:

```html
Add-Migration test2
```

```html
public partial class test2 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "NewColumn",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                nullable: true);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
          
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "NewColumn",
                table: "AspNetRoles");
        }
    }
```

3. Run EF update to add the new column:

```html
Update-Database
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a very simple way to do it.

Even though there's already an accepted answer, it doesn't show how to use it inside *DbContext*, that's why I decided to add mine.

**Step 1:**
Create a custom role

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string NewColumn { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Use it in `DbContext`

```
// string in <ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string> is the Key type
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

For more info on customizing Identity model, take a look at this Microsoft Learn guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0

`ApplicationUser` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

**Step 3:**
Open Package Manager Console and use following command to create new migration:

```
PM> Add-Migration 'Add new column to roles table'
```

**Step 4:**
Use following command to apply the migration into the database:

```
PM> Update-Database
```